# Console log not responding on handle change in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My `App.js` has the following code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import { Card, CardContent } from "@material-ui/core";
import Header from './Header';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

class App extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      topText: '',
      bottomText: '',
      randomImg: "http://i.imgflip.com/1bij.jpg",
      allImages: [],
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }  

  handleChange(event) {
    const {name, value} = event.target
    console.log("working")
    this.setState({ [name]: value })
  }


  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Grid container justify="left" spacing={8}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <TextField
              id="standard-name"
              label="Top Text"
              value={this.state.topText}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              margin="normal"
              variant="filled"
            />
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <TextField
              id="standard-name"
              label="Bottom Text"
              value={this.state.bottomText}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              margin="normal"
              variant="filled"
            />
          </Grid>
          <Header />
        </Grid>
      </div>      
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

`console.log("Working")` statement in `handleChange` does not respond to my inputs in the `TextField`. i.e. I don't see:

(1) any value being typed in the "Top Text" box

(2) I don't see "working" being displayed on the console

Comment: Are you saying that `console.log("working")` is working but value of input field is not changing

Comment: Please see the edit to my post

Comment: You are attempting to set value of each input via `value={this.state.bottomText}` and `value={this.state.topText}`, but you are setting state via `this.setState({ [name]: value })`. You don't have `name` properties on either input. Have you checked what `name` resolves to in handler `handleChange()`? Does it match `bottomText` or `topText`. If it doesn't the value of the inputs will not reflect correctly.

Comment: console log names - field names are different from state properties used for value

Comment: I tried  and works! https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-cdn-rmoim   o console.log works...

Comment: @Zanam try now....https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-cdn-rmoim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you weren't seeing "working" in the console. I did see "working" in the console with a near exact copy of your code. The main issue was not setting the "name" property on the `TextField`:

```
            <TextField
              id="standard-name"
              label="Top Text"
              name="topText"
              value={this.state.topText}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              margin="normal"
              variant="filled"
            />
```

Without the `name` property, your `handleChange` (`const {name, value} = event.target`) won't provide a name from `event.target`.

Here's an example based on your code with the first field fixed and the second one still exhibiting the issue:

https://codesandbox.io/s/textfield-missing-name-191bq

Answer (score 2):

I have copied your code to the Codesandbox and cleared it from unused imports.

https://codesandbox.io/s/table-9r5i9

1. Values are not changing because you forgot to add `name` property to `TextField`.
2. `console.log("working");` calls on typing into `TextField`.

You have one more issue. `Grid` component prints warning in console:

> Failed prop type: Invalid prop `justify` of value `left` supplied to `Grid`, expected one of ["flex-start","center","flex-end","space-between","space-around","space-evenly"].

Answer (score 0):

works for me:

you have to add name at textField

```
<TextField
                  id="standard-name"
                  label="Bottom Text"
                  name="bottomText"
```

and

```
 <TextField
              id="standard-name"
              name="topText"
```

the same name that you use in the state.

```
this.state = {
      topText: "",
      bottomText: "",
```

here all code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CardActionArea from "@material-ui/core/CardActionArea";
import { Card, CardContent } from "@material-ui/core";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      topText: "",
      bottomText: "",
      randomImg: "http://i.imgflip.com/1bij.jpg",
      allImages: []
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    console.log(name);
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Grid container justify="left" spacing={8}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <TextField
              id="standard-name"
              name="topText"
              label="Top Text"
              value={this.state.topText}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              margin="normal"
              variant="filled"
            />
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <TextField
              id="standard-name"
              label="Bottom Text"
              name="bottomText"
              value={this.state.bottomText}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              margin="normal"
              variant="filled"
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(, rootElement);

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-cdn-rmoim